# MYSQLI Prepared Statement Insert and lookup value From other table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a prepared statement that basically inserts data from an array into the table. but one of the columns I need to get from another table within the database. I came up with this thus far.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO stockimp si (sku,stock,status,productID) 
          VALUES (?,?,?,(SELECT post_id FROM postmeta pm  
          WHERE si.sku = pm.meta_value AND pm.meta_key = '_sku')) ";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt ->bind_param("sss", $dbSKU, $dbStock, $dbStatus);
$mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION");
```

It will work fine if I remove the select statement to get the post id and just set it to a static value. But I'm uncertain now at the best approach to take here. I know how to do it if it's just a direct copy of the table but with just grabbing one value from a column I'm not so sure.

Comment: The issue you could run in to here is if your sub-select returns multiple rows. Why not just select the `post_id` in a separate query before this one and then bind it in with the rest of your parameters?

Comment: @Phil Im trying to keep things to an utmost minimum. The databse is interacting with 10's of thousands of rows. Looking up the database in one query for each row would be quite a significant resource impact. Where as a prepared transaction it wil bulk run and would do it in a flash

Comment: _"Looking up the database in one query for each row would be quite a significant resource impact"_  do you know this for a fact?

Comment: Yes, I've already done it. IF your loppying throw 10's of thousands of rows and opening a query to the databse each time to get the value that equates to 10's of thousands of DB queries. Which I have done and the impact is quite significant. Hence wanting to do it as a single transaction

Comment: @phil P.s. if im missing something obvious just say it's 3 am where I am and I'm not exactly awake at this moment.

Comment: What's up with `WHERE si.sku = pm.meta_value`? Does that `si.sku` exist already or are you trying to refer to the value you're inserting?

Comment: That looks backwards. but yes we are refering the value inserted

Comment: Does that actually work or have you not tried this yet?

Comment: The above statement has been tried

Comment: And it works? That seems amazing.

Comment: No it doesnt work. Hence why we are here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not certain about what you're doing with that `SELECT` statement, particularly where you've got `si.sku = pm.meta_value` since you're inserting into the `si` table.

In any case, you could try using an [`INSERT...SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) instead with some parameterised values in the `SELECT`.

For example

```php
$sql = <<<_SQL
INSERT INTO stockimp (sku, stock, status, productID)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, pm.post_id
FROM postmeta pm
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_sku' AND pm.meta_value = ?
_SQL;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $dbSKU, $dbStock, $dbStatus, $dbSKU);
foreach ($arrayValues as list($dbSKU, $dbStock, $dbStatus)) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Note the repeated `$dbSKU` in the parameter list.

---

Personally, I would just use a couple of statements. Assuming your `$db*` values come from an array of values...

```php
// Prepare first, then loop for best performance
$postStmt = $mysqli->prepare(
        "SELECT post_id FROM postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' AND meta_value = ?");
$postStmt->bind_param('s', $dbSKU);

$inStmt = $mysqli->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO stockimp (sku, stock, status, productID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
$inStmt->bind_param('sssi', $dbSKU, $dbStock, $dbStatus, $postId);

foreach($arrayOfValues as list($dbSKU, $dbStock, $dbStatus)) {
    $postStmt->execute();
    $postStmt->bind_result($postId);
    while($postStmt->fetch()) {
        $inStmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Phill I actually just came up with something similar to your first one. testing now

Comment: I think you should also consider the second one, at least to compare the actual performance

Comment: No luck re the first one

Comment: What does that mean? Does it throw an error? What isn't working?

Comment: Sorry It through an error because of the table name. I ddnt provide the exact one and forgot to change it when testing it. It's running now. Ive got php tdoing an execution time usage time and runtime on it so ill try that one and vs it against the second one

Comment: Thanks for your help it will probobly be a while before I get back its close to 4am now here and im a bit worse for wear going to hit the bedness. Ill let you know tomoprrow how it went. Thanks again

Comment: Both came out about the same time. But both where very slow. The inser is like lighting. But as soon as the select is introduced. Bam And typing this out jsut made me think of something.

Comment: @DCdaz have you got an index on `postmeta` `meta_value` and `meta_key`?